# How to know where file is going to be saved?

Tags: finder, path

I have an application that is going to save a file to my MacBook Air El Capitan.  Trouble is, I cannot seem to find a way to determine where it's going to save the file in the dialog.  How do I find the FULL PATH of where it's going to save it?

The file save dialog appears to give me no way to determine this:

[image]

**Where is it going to save the file?**

Comment: You can always see the full (somehow inverted) path by clickin' on the drop-down menu (the current folder name) left to the search filed.

Comment: @klanomath So it just shows as a list, instead a path?

Comment: Yepp, it's no path like the common cli path. But both are only metaphors...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Click on position indicated by the red arrow in the figure below:

[image]

This will allow you to choose which folder/path you need. You can also use the Command - Shift - G to open the dialog to explicitly paste / type in a path.

- [Enter a filename in the File Open dialog](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/26819/enter-a-filename-in-the-file-open-dialog)
- [Save file to hidden directory with standard OS X save dialog](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164954/save-file-to-hidden-directory-with-standard-os-x-save-dialog)